# NameError when trying to access class attribute

Tags: python, nameerror

```
class Flight():
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.passengers = []
    def add_passenger(self, name):
        self.passengers.append(name)
    def check_availability(self):
        return self.capacity - len(self.passengers)

flight = Flight(3)
passengers_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
for x in passengers_list:
    if not self.check_availability:
        print(f"Sorry! No seat for {person}!!")
    else:
        flight.add_passenger(person)
        print(f"Seat for {person} is successfully booked!!")
```

This is a simple Python code trying to make sure that no flight is overbooked. But when I try to run this code, I get this error:

```
    if not self.check_availability:
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Specifically what about the error is unclear to you? What did you do to try to fix or debug the issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make an honest attempt at solving your problem first before posting.  For more tips, please read [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It looks like you wrote `self.check_availability` instead of `flight.check_availability()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is not a thing in the global scope.

You're defining `flight` as a Flight, so you'd need `if not flight.check_availability:`; and then `check_availability` is a function, so you need to call it. (If you don't call it, the `if` statement will always be false since a function is inherently truthy.)

```
if not flight.check_availability():
```

This is similar to what you're already doing with `flight.add_passenger()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works totally fine now!! But if `self` is not in a global scope, how is `return self.capacity - len(self.passengers)` working??

Comment: Because it's in a function that uses `self`?

Answer (score 1):

You made the mistake of putting `self` in the code outside of classes. You need to replace `self` with `flight`.

```
if not flight.check_availability():
```

should be what you are looking for.